# Dark spots suddenly appear on the screen then phone reboots. Bug or virus?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bugs

I have been experiencing this problem since I bought this phone, which is an Infinix HOT 4 Lite. I thought it was a virus because I installed a lot of applications then, so I did a Factory Reset. The problem was persistent. The following happens to the screen first:

[image]

Then it stops responding, until it reboots again. I noticed that this happens when I turn on the screen, but not always. OS version is Marshmallow (Android 6.0), and it is not rooted. I searched Google a bit but I couldn't find anything related to this case.

Comment: The pattern is displayed *behind* the notifications at the top, so can you try to drag down the notification tray and get to the settings that way? Or when it doesn't happen, check if any unexpected apps have the "Draw over other apps" permission.

Comment: @Dan I can't get to the notification tray because the phone stops responding. And for the permission, there are tons of apps with the permission but I suspect only 2 which are Opera Mini and Xender. I have been using these two long ago, so I don't think they are the problem too. The other apps are either system apps or those I installed after I encountered the problem.

Comment: If you can (if the issue occurs surely and often enough for you to catch it easily), run `adb logcat` then capture the log of when this happens.

Comment: @AndyYan The screen stays like in the screenshot for about 5 seconds till it reboots. It's a pretty short interval since this occurs almost randomly. But when I am practicing Android Development on Android Studio, I use my phone for testing, so I was wondering if I can run it from there when the opportunity strikes.